# How can I transform the sentence into passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

How can I use the **passive voice** in the next sentence?

> "Don't play on the grass, boys," she said.

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence contains a quotation. If I was asked to modify the *structure* of a sentence I would not change the quotation, otherwise, you now have a *misquote*.

As the only part of the sentence *not* a quotation is "*she said*", the only way I can see you can make this passive would be:

> "Don't play on the grass, boys," *was said by her*.

Comment: It's only a misquote if you're actually quoting a real person. If you're writing a story, then it's perfectly reasonable to change what's inside the quotation marks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the sentence in quotes into the passive voice in the following way:

> "The grass is not to be played on, boys," she said.

This sentence is a little softer, since it emphasizes that there's a rule against playing on the grass, rather than the fact that the boys are playing on the grass and therefore breaking the rule.

I might say it this way if I were talking to someone else's children. If I were talking to my own children, I'd definitely say, "Don't play on the grass, boys."